# Removing a blank property from a UILabel when using Core Data and Table View Controllers

Tags: ios, uilabel, uitableview

I have a problem where I believe there is an extremely simple solution, but I just cannot find what that is.

I have a TableViewController which is populated by a user going into another view and filling in some text fields.

The table view cell has a custom label which updates according to what the user puts in, and the table view is getting updated with NSFetchedResultsController while I'm using Core Data for the data model.

I have an event and a sub event that the user fills in; the sub event is optional.

I want to get it to a stage where, if the user enters an event and sub event, it's displayed as event(sub event) but if the user enters only an event and not a sub event, it should just be event as the UILabel.

Here's the code:

```
if (transaction.subevent)
{
    customCell.eventLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)", transaction.occasion.title, transaction.subevent.title];
}
else
{
    customCell.eventLabel.text = transaction.occasion.title;
}
```

If the user enters a sub event and an event, I'm getting:

event (subevent) as the UILabel which is correct.

However, if the user enters only an event and not a sub event, I get:

event () as the UILabel which is incorrect.

This of course means it's within the if statement, rather than the else. Both events and sub events are strings and I'm missing a very obvious way of fixing this.

Any light shed on this would be really great.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that transaction.subevent is not nil, even though the user did not enter anything. You can try testing for `transaction.subevent.title.length == 0` instead.

**UPDATE**

For reference, here is Wil Shipley's famous(?) isEmpty (with an added test for NSNull), for even more fail-safe usage. Although it is not really necessary in this use case:

```
static inline BOOL IsEmpty(id thing) {
    return thing == nil
    || thing == [NSNull null]
    || ([thing respondsToSelector:@selector(length)]
    && [(NSData *)thing length] == 0)
    || ([thing respondsToSelector:@selector(count)]
    && [(NSArray *)thing count] == 0);
}
```

Comment: @david-souther Why title? There is no way of knowing what kind of element the subevent is, as the OP does not state it. Most likely, it does not have a title property

Comment: the OP sets it to the label's text property as an NSString object in the code snippet.

Comment: Dear David-souther and @Marius and Preson - Many thanks for the reply. With if ([transaction.subevent.title length] > 0) - this works as expected with the transactions without a sub event showing only "event" and no (). I have not tested all scenarios here, but this seems like a reasonable way to approach this? If this works, I'm happy and thank you!

Comment: Yes @Lavanya, this is the way to test it. There is an even more fail-safe approach, using Wil Shipleys isempty. I will add it to the answer, but it is not necessary in your case

Comment: @MariusFalkenbergWaldal - That's super - many thanks for sending that in. That really is brilliant. As you say, I may not use it in this case bt I'm keeping it for reference! Thanks for the quick save to this one - really appreciate it!